# SceneKit : Extract data from SCNGeometryElement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, scenekit

I am using SceneKit, and I have an issue:

How can I extract the data from a `SCNGeometryElement` object ?
I use this method :

```
- (void)geometryElements:(SCNNode *)node {
for (int indexElement = 0; indexElement < node.geometry.geometryElementCount; indexElement++) {
    SCNGeometryElement *currentElement = [node.geometry geometryElementAtIndex:indexElement];

    NSLog(@"\n");
    NSLog(@"bytes per index : %d", currentElement.bytesPerIndex);
    NSLog(@"number element : %d", currentElement.primitiveCount);
    NSLog(@"data lenght : %d", currentElement.data.length);

    for (int indexPrimitive = 0; indexPrimitive < currentElement.primitiveCount; indexPrimitive++) {
        int array[3];
        memset(array, 0, 3);

        [currentElement.data getBytes:&array range:NSMakeRange(indexPrimitive * 3, (currentElement.bytesPerIndex * 3))];

        NSLog(@"currentelement : %d %d %d", array[0], array[1], array[3]);
    }
}
```

The result is not good :

```
2015-04-10 15:10:25.183 IKTest[1234:244778] currentelement : 14539995     -1068223968 -379286778
2015-04-10 15:10:25.183 IKTest[1234:244778] currentelement : 14737374 -1068223968 -379286778
2015-04-10 15:10:25.183 IKTest[1234:244778] currentelement : 14934753 -1068223968 -379286778
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Objective-C code, why is the question tagged with [swift] ?

Comment: I believe you should be using uint instead of int. Can you try? (also print with %u instead of %d)

Comment: From the documentation: *"An element’s data is an array of index values identifying vertices in a geometry source. SceneKit interprets the data as an array of unsigned integers, whose size is specified by the bytesPerIndex property."*. I have no experience with SCNGeometryElement, but according to the docs it could be 8-, 16-, 32- or 64-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: Doesn't work with uint type.

Comment: I can't find some example on internet.

Answer (score 2):

a few notes:

- you should rely on `geometryElement.primitiveType` instead of hard coding `3` (unless you are sure that you're always dealing with `SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangles`)
- it seems that the range's location does not take `geometryElement.bytesPerIndex` into account
- your buffer is of size `3 * sizeof(int)` but should be of size `numberOfIndicesPerPrimitive  * geometryElement.bytesPerIndex`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't save me. i replace all variable. it seems impossible to get something clear.

Comment: i tried with : "CFSwapInt16(*(ushort*)([data4 bytes]));" still not working. I passed 3 days on it, i think it's impossible.

Comment: `CFSwapInt16` changes the endianness of an integer, so it's useless here. What you need to do is to check what `bytesPerIndex` is, and make sure (with `if`s or a `case`) that you are always dealing with the right type.

Answer (score 0):

As mnuages said, you should confirm primtive type and data type of index first.
Your code only work if index type is `int`.

Here is some code work for me. I only deals that geometry consisted of triangles.

```
void extractInfoFromGeoElement(NSString* scenePath){
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:scenePath];
    SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:url options:nil error:nil];
    SCNGeometry *geo = scene.rootNode.childNodes.firstObject.geometry;
    SCNGeometryElement *elem = geo.geometryElements.firstObject;
    NSInteger componentOfPrimitive = (elem.primitiveType == SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangles) ? 3 : 0;
    if (!componentOfPrimitive) {//TODO: Code deals with triangle primitive only
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<elem.primitiveCount; i++) {
        void *idxsPtr = NULL;
        int stride = 3*i;
        if (elem.bytesPerIndex == 2) {
            short *idxsShort = malloc(sizeof(short)*3);
            idxsPtr = idxsShort;
        }else if (elem.bytesPerIndex == 4){
            int *idxsInt = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
            idxsPtr = idxsInt;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"unknow index type");
            return;
        }
        [elem.data getBytes:idxsPtr range:NSMakeRange(stride*elem.bytesPerIndex, elem.bytesPerIndex*3)];
        if (elem.bytesPerIndex == 2) {
            NSLog(@"triangle %d : %d, %d, %d\n",i,*(short*)idxsPtr,*((short*)idxsPtr+1),*((short*)idxsPtr+2));
        }else{
            NSLog(@"triangle %d : %d, %d, %d\n",i,*(int*)idxsPtr,*((int*)idxsPtr+1),*((int*)idxsPtr+2));
        }
        //Free
        free(idxsPtr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the original question has a Swift tag, I am posting my solution in Swift 5.

```
extension SCNGeometryElement {

/// Gets the `Element` vertices
func getVertices() -> [SCNVector3] {
    
    func vectorFromData<UInt: BinaryInteger>(_ float: UInt.Type, index: Int) -> SCNVector3 {
        assert(bytesPerIndex == MemoryLayout<UInt>.size)
        let vectorData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>.allocate(capacity: bytesPerIndex)
        let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: vectorData, count: primitiveCount)
        let stride = 3 * index
        self.data.copyBytes(to: buffer, from: stride * bytesPerIndex..<(stride * bytesPerIndex) + 3)
        return SCNVector3(
            CGFloat.NativeType(vectorData[0]),
            CGFloat.NativeType(vectorData[1]),
            CGFloat.NativeType(vectorData[2])
        )
    }
    
    let vectors = [SCNVector3](repeating: SCNVector3Zero, count: self.primitiveCount)
    return vectors.indices.map { index -> SCNVector3 in
        switch bytesPerIndex {
            case 2:
                return vectorFromData(Int16.self, index: index)
            case 4:
                return vectorFromData(Int.self, index: index)
            case 8:
                return SCNVector3Zero
            default:
                return SCNVector3Zero
        }
    }
}
}
```

There might be a bit of an indentation problem here, but yes, it is a function inside another one. The objective is the same as the other answers. Create a buffer, define what types of numbers the buffer is going to handle, build the `SCNVector3` and return the array.